# How to fix link wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink

I have a problem with my links. I am using Wordpress and when I add a html link in the footer like this example;

```
<a href=“https://www.website.nl/“>Website</a>.
```

It opens the link on the same page like this:

```
https://www.website1.nl/“https://www.website.nl/
```

How can I fix this?

Kind Regards

Comment: How do you add HTML in the footer?

Comment: Can you try with proper double quotes? If you want to open in new tab then use attribute _target="blank".

Answer (score 0):

I think it is quotes issue
Please try with below:

```
<a href="https://www.website.nl/">Website</a>.
```

Comment: I use that HTML code but it doesn’t open my website link but it opens this link.

https://www.website1.nl/“https://www.website.nl/

Comment: Have you defined anywhere the "website1.nl"?